# Read Custom variable's data using google analytics api c#

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I'm trying to use the **Google Analytics API C#** to retrieve custom varaibles's from google analytics. I try this [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-fetch-google-analytics-statistics-and-display-it-in-y](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-fetch-google-analytics-statistics-and-display-it-in-y/) and I can read custom dimension data, but I want to read custom variable's data, which is always return null. My code is given below :

```
  // path of my .p12 file
  string keyFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("path/of/my/.p12");
  string serviceAccountEmail = "xxx-xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
  string websiteCode = "xxxxxxxxx"; 

  string keyPassword = "notasecret";

  AnalyticsService service = null; 

  var scopes =
          new string[] {     
             AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics,              // view and manage your analytics data    
             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit,          // edit management actives    
             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers,   // manage users    
             AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly};     // View analytics data    


  var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));


service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(
           "ga:" + websiteCode,
           DateTime.Today.AddDays(-15).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
           DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
           "ga:sessions,ga:users");

     request.Dimensions = "ga:dimension1";
     // is it possible to add custom variable here
     // return exception bcz no such dimension which named: "CustomVar1"
     // request.Dimensions = "ga:CustomVar1";  

    var data = request.Execute();

    // data.Row is always null
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `request.Dimensions = "ga:dimension1";` you use your dimentoin, not your custom variable. You just change the that line to the following code

```
request.Dimensions = "ga:customVarName1";
// or you can use request.Dimensions = "ga:customVarValue1";
```

For more about custom variable read [google custom variable reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) and to retrieve custom variable read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns, hope your problem will be solved.